# Stop JavaScript after execution

Tags: javascript, setinterval

How do I stop JavaScript after execution?

I create one javascript for post in chat one text if other people say a keyword.
But the script send the message and not stop.

Now the code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery('#frame_chatbox')
        .replaceWith('<iframe id="framejqs" src="/chatbox" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    jQuery('#framejqs').contents()
        .find('#chatbox_footer #chatbox_messenger_form #submit_button')
        .click(function() {
            if(jQuery('#framejqs').contents()
                .find('#chatbox_footer #chatbox_messenger_form input[name="message"]')
                .val().indexOf('HERE THE KEYWORD') != -1) {
                    $.post('/chatbox/chatbox_actions.forum?archives',
                           {mode:"send", sent:"HERE THE MENS"});
                    return false;
            }
        });
});
```

http://pastebin.com/5KF9R5Rv

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, a Portuguese version of stackoverflow does exist if that language is more convenient to you: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sends the message repeatedly because the sending function is wrapped in an interval firing once per millisecond (the second argument is missing):

```
setInterval(function () {
    // ...
}, time_between_sends);
```

The `time_between_sends` defines how much time passes by between different calls of the function you passed into `setInterval` as first argument.

For example:

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log(new Date());  // logs the date once per second (1000ms === 1s)
}, 1000);
```

More generally, I'd consider using an event listener instead of an interval though.

Comment: Thank you. But putting the time_between_sends, if otther user say the keyword, the screep not activate.

Comment: You're checking the complete chat history in this function, right? So, if the keyword you're looking for appears once or more in the history,  the `indexOf` condition will be true, thus the message will be sent again. Maybe only check the latest record in the chat history?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **[clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)**

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  //your code
  if(condition to stop interval)
  {
    clearInterval(interval);//clearing interval when you want
  }
});
```

Here is [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/NkwAN/)

### Update

If you want to stop it after you got response from post method you can do something like following:

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NkwAN/1/)

Code:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
    $.post('/echo/html/','',function(){
        myStopFunction()//calling method to stop setInterval
    });
}, 1000);


function myStopFunction() {
    alert("stoping");
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Comment: Can i execute the "clearInterval(interval);" immediately after the execution?
If yes, how i do?

Comment: Ya sure you ca execute it anywhere you want @VictorEyer

Comment: Now, the javascrip immediately stoped.

Comment: No victor you are going to wrong direction. `clearInterval()` on document load stop your function. Tell me exactly when you want to stop `setInterval`??

Comment: After this:   $.post('/chatbox/chatbox_actions.forum?archives',
                           {mode:"send", sent:"HERE THE MENS"});